# how to convert String into Integer in java

Tags: java

I want to convert `String` to `int`
If the String contain character it will return 0
Else it will return the number 
For example the conversion of (ad12) is 0
But  (12) Is 12

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaFX, this is just plain Java. Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String- and watch for the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: I try it but, but when I put a character, i had this error                'Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at control.ControllerSaisie$1.handle(ControllerSaisie.java:169)
'

Comment: Try/Catch Block? Or examine the String before? SO is not for explaining Java basics, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
public int getInt(String test){
        try{
            return Integer.parseInt(test.trim());
        }catch(Exception e){
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

All you need to do is use `Integer` class to get int value of valid integer containing string.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to parse it and catch the exception

```
public static int stringToInt(String s) {
    try {
        return Integer.valueOf(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use IntegerStringConverter class instance to convert Integer to String or vice versa.
`IntegerStringConverter isc=new IntegerStringConverter();
int a=isc.fromString("Your String"); //It converts String to Integer
String str=isc.toString(Integer Value);   //It converts Integer to String`